# Mouse and Keyboard Take Several Minutes After Boot to Function

Tags: boot, usb, keyboard, mouse, startup

I feel like I've seen someone else mention this online but I'm having the hardest time finding this specific issue and not some variant. My usb mouse and keyboard function fine in Ubuntu, and in bios, but when the login screen appears it takes several minutes for my devices to work. It's not a huge issue, it just confuses me as Windows 10 doesn't do this, and thus by comparison starts up faster for me. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04 on an intel system with a pci usb card, but the issue was present before that, and is consistent across all the usb ports in my system.

Comment: Look at your system startup logs with `sudo journalctl  -b 0` (for the current boot). Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Modern windows uses *fastboot* which doesn't actually boot; just loads a *hibernate* file that is created when you update your system (it's the hibernated image of a clean boot) so your comparison maybe invalid (are you cold booting windows? or just loading the *fastboot* hibernate file). Several minutes is not normal, are you sure it's USB and not just the GUI?  (can you use a text terminal? is it the same if you boot to runlevel 1? or text mode only? how far did you explore?)